# Problem with phosphorylated and total forms of antibodies

Tags: molecular-biology

Antibodies are available that can detect both phosphorylated and total endogeneous levels of the given protein. I have a question here, why is it necessary to have equal amounts of total protein? This is a common assumption that variations come in phosphorylation status but since total detects levels of both phosphorylated and non-phosphorylated forms, it is supposed to be equal. Not necessarily! Depending on the requirement of cells, phosphorylation status may change. And so does the expression of the total protein itself specially if the non-phosphorylated form is acting as a transcription factor.This is what I find in my studies as well. But the literature suggests the opposite. Why?